# How to convert json response to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I received json object with multiple array  and under the array have many sub array.How to convert php array??

```
Object {
    que: Array[2], 

    cmd: Array[0], 

    _bidsRequested: Array[2], 

    _bidsReceived: Array[2]

    0: ad: "3924e7bfe" adUnitCode: "div-gpt-23"

    1:ad: "3924e7bfe" adUnitCode: "div-gpt-24"
}
```

I want only the ad variable under _bidsReceived array

```
a=3924e7bfy
b=3924e7bfe
```

Comment: [There's no such thing as a JSON Object ?](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: it is a json object

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your code is that you have received a JSON response which has a few keys that have an array as a value.

Step 1 : Convert your JSON response to PHP Array

```
$phpArray = json_decode($jsonResponse,true);
```

Step : Now you have a PHP Array which you can tweak to what you need.

```
$a = $phpArray["_bidsReceived"][0]["ad"];
$b = $phpArray["_bidsReceived"][1]["ad"];
```

If you can give me the exact JSON response you get in a string format, I can write the exact code for you to deploy.